# Strength of "Every finite dimensional subspace of a vector space has a complement"

Tags: linear-algebra, reference-request, vector-spaces, axiom-of-choice, axioms

Does the following choice principle have a name?

> Every finite dimensional subspace of a vector space has a complement. Equivalently, every line inside a vector space has a complementary hyperplane.

How strong/weak is it compared to other choice principles? It certainly follows from the existence of a basis, and as such is a consequence of the axiom of choice.

*Feel free to edit the Tags, I wasn't sure which tag is appropriate.*

Comment: Oh, that's a nice question!

Comment: I don't think it has been addressed in the literature, by the way. My guess, if anything, is that this is going to be weaker than the Boolean Prime Ideal theorem, and unrelated to countable choice and the likes of it. It is certainly not provable without the axiom of choice, though.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I'm glad you like it :)

Comment: Yeah, after double checking (and finding out a paper that would have been helpful when I wrote my M.Sc. thesis two years ago), I found some papers which reviewed fairly relevant results and it said nothing on this particular principle. My guess is that if there is an answer given here, it will be the first time this has been formulated and answered. So let me inquire further, where did you run into this?

Comment: @AsafKaragila I came up with it an hour ago, I don't remember why :| It's certainly of no immediate importance to me, I asked out of pure curiosity.

Comment: I fear that you might not get a good answer anytime soon. But it's a great question, nonetheless.

Comment: @AsafKaragila That's alright.

Answer (score 1):

As a lower bound on the strength of this, by [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/194316/75) of mine on MO, "every line has a complementary hyperplane" implies the axiom of choice for finite sets of bounded cardinality.  More precisely, that answer shows that if $X$ is a set such that there exists an $\mathbb{F}_p$-hyperplane in the space $\mathbb{F}_p(X)$ of rational functions with elements of $X$ as variables for all primes $p\leq n$, then there is a choice function on the subsets of $X$ of cardinality $\leq n$.